# BDM pads on a Renault 450 DXI (EURO 5) Truck ECU

Tags: flash, jtag, obd

I'm trying to find the BDM pads for connection and map download from a Renault 450 DXI (euro 5) truck.

Attached is a picture of the ECU.

The control unit is MPC5XX ECU TRW EMS 2.2

[image: ECU]

Other details on the control unit are, 314D08254183 EMS2.2 Min A. above which the characters 59312307C are printed on the board.

For reference i have attached the documentation i have been working from to locate the pads, however it is pointing to an ECU TRW EMS2, which appears different.

[image: ECU manual pg1]
[image: ecu manual pg2]
[image: ECU manual pg3]

Any information, or guidance would be greatly apprecated.

Tony

Comment: Can you post the other side of the PCB? BDM isn't particularly fast and the test points should live fairly close to the target MCU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read that ECU like a Volvo Truck/ Fmx / TRW EMS2 de 450HP. Use KTAG with the rainbow cable number 144300T 105 with 24v and 5 amps. Good look! Ths ECU is used on a Renault Truck with Volvo engine. To write it only under OBDII.